# Angular 2 - Implement UrlSerializer

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement my own UrlSerializer class, this is what I did:

```
import { UrlSerializer,UrlTree } from '@angular/router';

export class CustomUrlSerializer implements UrlSerializer {

    parse(url: string): UrlTree {
        // Change plus signs to encoded spaces
        url.replace("%20", '-');
        // Use the default serializer that you can import to just do the 
        // default parsing now that you have fixed the url.
        return super.parse(url)  
    }

    serialize(tree: UrlTree): string {
        // Use the default serializer to create a url and replace any spaces with + signs
        return super.serialize(tree).replace("%20", '-');
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to compile I get the following erros:

```
c:/xampp/htdocs/proj/src/app/custom-url-serializer.ts (11,12): 'super' can only be referenced in a derived class.
c:/xampp/htdocs/proj/src/app/custom-url-serializer.ts (16,12): 'super' can only be referenced in a derived class.
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say the problem is the `implements` keyword. Because it expect an interface, which has no implementation, so you cannot call `super`. The `UrlSerializer` is an abstract class, so you could use the `DefaultUrlSerializer`:

```
import { DefaultUrlSerializer, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
class CustomUrlSerializer extends DefaultUrlSerializer {
    parse(url: string) : UrlTree {
        return super.parse(url);
    }
}
new CustomUrlSerializer().parse('http://stackoverflow.com');
```

It should work.

Comment: UrlSerializer is an abstract method, now I get an error that I can't use super. How I can access the default url serializer?

Comment: Ah, yes, that's true. You can use DefaultUrlSerializer https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/DefaultUrlSerializer-class.html

Comment: Thanks! But how I can import it to my custom class? there is no constructor for abstracts

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly mean, but I edited my answer to include more code and the `DefaultUrlSerializer`. I tried that example and it worked well.

Comment: In case anyone is still wondering: you should add it to your root app module providers, e.g. 
@NgModule({
providers:[{provide: UrlSerializer, useClass: CustomUrlSerializer }, /*more providers*/], /*bootstrap etc*/ })
export class myApp { /*etc*/ }