# How to encode query params containing special characters in Angular 7?

Tags: javascript, angular, http, angular7, urlencode

I am trying to encode query parameter values in Angular 7. But I get 400 Bad Request status code, when my query parameter values contain any special character

Failed Request URL:
http://localhost/api/67/cardvalues?parentcardvalues=STONE&parentcardvalues=STONE%20AGE

However, I get 200 OK status code , when my query parameter values do not contain any special characters.

Successful Request URL:
http://localhost/api/67/cardvalues?parentcardvalues=STONE&parentcardvalues=STONE

The expected request url has to be like 
http://localhost/cardvalues?parentcardvalues=VALUE1&parentcardvalues=VALUE2

Below is my code,

```
parentcardvalues=["STONE","STONE AGE"]

let myparams = new HttpParams();

    if(parentcardvalues.length != 0)
       parentcardvalues.forEach((value) => { 

myparams = myparams.append( 'parentcardvalues',   encodeURIComponent(value) );

});

 this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'api/67/cardvalues', {params: myparams});
```

The Swagger specification is,

Curl

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost/api/cardvalues?parentcardvalues=STONE&parentcardvalues=STONE%20AGE" -H  "accept: application/json"
```

Request URL

```
http://localhost/api/cardvalues?parentcardvalues=STONE&parentcardvalues=STONE%20AGE
```

Comment: I doubt you have to have the `?` if you use `params`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks, I still get same error after removing the extra  " ? ". I was wondering if I need to set some options with my request header

Comment: Sounds like a back end problem. using `%20` for space is uri encoding standard

Answer (score 5):

you can decode your params using:

```
decodeURIComponent(encodedURI_string)
```

more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

Answer (score 2):

I created a new Encoder class:

```js
import { HttpParameterCodec } from '@angular/common/http';

export class CustomHttpParamEncoder implements HttpParameterCodec {
  encodeKey(key: string): string {
    return encodeURIComponent(key);
  }

  encodeValue(value: string): string {
    return encodeURIComponent(value);
  }

  decodeKey(key: string): string {
    return decodeURIComponent(key);
  }

  decodeValue(value: string): string {
    return decodeURIComponent(value);
  }
}
```

and then use it in the requests where I need it.

```js
const params = new HttpParams({ encoder: new CustomHttpParamEncoder() })
  .set('parentcardvalues', value);
return this.httpClient.get(url, { params });
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree, and you can do a general change with urls problems with chars in urlserializer:
https://angular.io/api/router/DefaultUrlSerializer
https://angular.io/api/router/UrlSerializer

You can overwrite this in app.module.ts (provide:{..,..})
You can see this: 
[Angular 2 - Implement UrlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43399936/angular-2-implement-urlserializer)

regards